# Does Adobe Air support KEEP ALIVEs / persistent HTTP connections

Tags: adobe, air

As far as I can tell Adobe Air does not support persistent HTTP connections via KEEP ALIVEs.

Does anyone know any different?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Air runs on Webkit, so you can use the Web Sockets API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently building an application that connects to a Comet-style long-poll API. To keep connections open, just make sure to set `URLRequestDefaults.idleTimeout` to some sensible value (the default varies from system to system but is probably around 30 seconds). I am successfully keeping connections open for 15 minutes at a time. You may also need to add a Connection: Keep-Alive header like so:

```
myRequest.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive"));
```